# Uniq on array, not displaying correctly

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, loops

I am new to bash programming and I am struggling with arrays and how to operate with them.
SCENARIO:

I have a variable called x which is composed of a group of IP's.
This is the output when I **echo $x** from my script

```
182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 201.21.24.22 201.21.24.22 201.21.24.22
44.21.25.31 44.21.25.31 44.21.25.31 44.21.25.31
```

Then, I would like to know how many times each IP is repeated.
The desired output would be:

```
15 182.100.67.59
4 44.21.25.31
3 201.21.24.22
```

I have tried the following

```
(IFS=" "; sort <<< "$x" ) | uniq -c
```

Output Note the first 1 on the output.

```
**1** 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 201.21.24.22 201.21.24.22 201.21.24.22 44.21.25.31 44.21.25.31 44.21.25.31 44.21.25.31
```

I am not seeing this, It should be pretty simple but I can't find the solution :(
Thanks! And very great community!

Comment: IFS changes how the shell splits records into fields, but in `sort <<< "$x"` there's no splitting of records into fields going on at all; the whole variable is being passed on the stdin of `sort` (which is a separate program, not part of the shell) exactly as it is, without the shell changing it in any way.

Comment: Note also that `echo $x` is quite uninformative about what your variable `x` actually contains. It changes all runs of whitespace to a single space each (hiding newlines), replaces anything that can be parsed as a glob expression as a list of files that glob identifies, silently discards everything but the first item if your variable is an array, and has some other most-likely-unwanted behaviors as well. Best to use `declare -p x`, though `echo "$x"` is better than no improvement at all.

Comment: Oh thanks @CharlesDuffy so the problem resides on IFS. Glad to know, what do you think it would be the best approach to solve this?

Comment: What I meant to convey is more that IFS doesn't have anything to do with it (because there's no field-splitting happening, the variable that controls field splitting isn't relevant here). The intent of the comment was more to explain _why_ the attempt with calling `sort` after setting `IFS` didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1:**
Use `tr` to replace spaces with newlines, followed by `sort | uniq -c`:

```
tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$x" | sort | uniq -c
```

**Method 2:**
Use `echo` with `xargs -n1` to write the IPs one per line, followed by `sort | uniq -c`. Note that `xargs` is slower than `tr` here, plus may have potential side effects, such as quote removal:

```
echo "$x" | xargs -n1 | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for arrays here.

A simple pipeline using `grep`, `sort` and `uniq` will do the trick:

```
echo "$x" | grep -Eo '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't have an array, per se; you have a string of numbers separated by spaces. If `echo $x` gives the value you specify, this is the case and the answer is:

```
aips=( ${x} )
printf "%s\n" "${aips[@]}"  | sort | uniq -c
```

This converts the string of numbers separated by spaces (`IFS`) into the array `aips` (the parens specify this is an array as opposed to a string), and then uses `printf` with the behavior that it re-uses the format specification when there are more arguments than the format specification specifies, to print every element of the array (`${aips[@]}`) followed by a newline, then sorts and `uniq`s it.

Had this been a real array (e.g. `x=( "182.100.67.59" "201.21.24.22" ...)`) the answer would be just the latter part:

```
printf "%s\n" "${x[@]}" | sort | uniq -c

 15 182.100.67.59
  3 201.21.24.22
  4 44.21.25.31
```

Comment: Given that `echo $x` displayed all the IPs, it clearly was not an array (or the OP was using zsh rather than bash -- but in bash, `$array` expands to only the first element).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Point well taken, I answered the question in the headline instead of the one detailed in the question. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Note that `aips=( ${x} )` is [considered an antipattern](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29) -- it doesn't _just_ split items into an array on IFS, but also expands globs in the content, and is correspondingly subject to the shell's various glob-related configuration (`nullglob`, `failglob`, etc). `read -r -a aips <<<"$x"` is more predictable.

Comment: (caveat for completeness: if a variable may have multiple lines, one may need `read -r -d '' -a apis < <(printf '%s\0' "$aips")`; without the `-d`, the `read` will only consume a single line; _with_ the `-d`, it reads until it sees a delimiter or EOF, but will return false if the delimiter is not seen -- hence injecting a NUL at the end after the string is successfully written).